# Sitecore webforms for marketers save item action

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

How can I map the value of a form field to the name of the item created by Webforms for marketers save action "Create Item".

At the moment all the items created have the same item name, the item name is that if the template they are created from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do the following:

- on a "Mapping Form Fields" step of the wizard turn the "Show Standard Fields" checkbox ON
- map the desired field of your form to `__Display name` field of the item

This should have the same effect you'd like to have.

Comment: I thought that too, but when I check that box I do not see any more fields, my template is built on the standard template - I thought this would give me the basic fields to amend but nothing more is shown.

Comment: No you are right - my machine wasnt showing the standard fields for whatever reason.. reboot fixed it.. I dont know. - Another question now though, I need a value for the form to map to the __Display name and name in the item, I tried $name but that uses the template name.

Comment: I don't understand your second question... As far as I know, the value of the form field that you'll map to __Display name will be used as a value for __Display name. The real name of the item will be something by default, but you should not care - the Content Editor will display a different name for each item

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear.. there is a field, company name, this needs to be used for both the __display name (so that items are easy for the client to manage) and the template field company name, I can only see the ability to do a 1 to 1 mapping.. meaning I can map the web for value for company name to the __display name, but I cant also map it to the item field company name - I'm sure I am just missing something.

Comment: fair enough, bit of a shame as it would be very handy.